# Какое свойство TStrinGrid отвечает за возмеожность изменения ширины колонок в рантайм?

Tags: delphi

Какое свойство TStrinGrid отвечает за возмеожность изменения ширины колонок в рантайм?

Answer (score 1):

`Properties -> Options -> goColSizing`